# Not able to change Eclipse property view value

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create Eclipse plugin application where on selction of a node in a treeViewer show corresponding value in eclipse property view. 
I have implemented the class which overrides `IPropertySource` interface like below:

```
public class PropertyViewer implements IPropertySource
{
@Override
public Object getEditableValue() 
{
    return this;
}

@Override
public IPropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors() {
    return desc;
}

@Override
public Object getPropertyValue(Object id) {
    application specific logic yo return value for a id
}

@Override
public boolean isPropertySet(Object id) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void resetPropertyValue(Object id) {

}

@Override
public void setPropertyValue(Object id, Object value) {
    //to set vlaue for a changed property in eclipse property view
}}
```

Now the problem with above code is that the `setPropertyValue` is called correctly when the update is done on the eclipse property. but the updated property is not shown inside eclipse property view on enter. But when I deselct and select this node again its showing the updated value. I googled a lot and got the `firePropertyChange` method have to called under `setpropertyValue` function. Can anyone help me on this since I am not at all familiar with this. A small code snippet which shows how to call fireproperty change will be help full. Thanks a lot in advance. Tor